# How to remove item selected from combobox from another combobox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

The list of items from two combobox is the same. My problem is that, if i select an item from 1st combobox , i wanted to remove or not show that item from the 2nd combobox but the item will remain in the 1st combobox.

```cs
//////////////this is how i fill combobox
public void fillcombobox()
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM candidate_list";
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (mdr.Read())
            {
               if (mdr.GetString("candidate_position").Equals("PRO"))
                {
                    //PRO1
                    cbo_Pro1.Text = "-- SELECT CANDIDATE --";
                    cbo_Pro2.Text = "-- SELECT CANDIDATE --";
                    string fname = mdr.GetString("candidate_name");
                    string spacee = " ";
                    string lname = mdr.GetString("candidate_surname");
                    cbo_Pro1.Items.Add(fname + spacee + lname);
                    cbo_Pro2.Items.Add(fname + spacee + lname);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }


////////////this is the event for 1st combobox

private void cbo_Pro1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pro1Name = cbo_Pro1.Text.Split(null);

        String selectQuery = "Select * FROM candidate_list WHERE candidate_name LIKE '%" + pro1Name[0] + "%'";

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();


        da.Fill(table);

        byte[] image = (byte[])table.Rows[0][5];

        pictureBox8.Image = byteArrayToImage(image);

        da.Dispose();

    }

//////////////////this is the event for second combobox

private void cbo_Pro2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pro2Name = cbo_Pro2.Text.Split(null);

        String selectQuery = "Select * FROM candidate_list WHERE candidate_name LIKE '%" + pro2Name[0] + "%'";

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();


        da.Fill(table);

        byte[] image = (byte[])table.Rows[0][5];

        pictureBox9.Image = byteArrayToImage(image);

        da.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: What you should do is create a main view you can filter, no need to load data every time... Then you filter the views....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said both ComboBox's have the exactly same items so,

it's easy something like this:

```
private void cbo_Pro1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     cbo_Pro2.Items.Remove(cbo_Pro1.Text);
}
```

Basically, when you select one item in cbo_Pro1, remove that specific item on cbo_Pro2..

Comment: ohh wow im overthinking for the solution to my problem . and the solution is very simple. jeez XD . thanks for the help